# How to rewrite history for multiple branches simultaneously?

Tags: git, rebase

With interactive rebase (`git -i rebase ...`) one can edit commits anywhere in the current branch's lineage, thus "rewriting history".

A given commit, however, can belong to the lineages of multiple branches.

For example, suppose I have a repo with this branch structure:

```
A --- B --- C --- D --- F --- G  branch_1*
             \
              `-- H --- I --- J  branch_2
                         \
                          `-- K  branch_3
```

If the active branch is `branch_1`, and I use `rebase -i` to edit commit `B`, the resulting repo would look like this (at least until GC happens):

```
  ,-- b --- c --- d --- f --- g  branch_1*
 /
A --- B --- C --- D --- F --- G
             \
              `-- H --- I --- J  branch_2
                         \
                          `-- K  branch_3
```

Note that the original `B` continues to be in the lineages of `branch_2` and `branch_1`.  Repeating the process for each of these branches, as tedious as that would be, would result in multiple redundant commits, and the original branch structure would be lost:

```
  ,-- b --- c --- d --- f --- g  branch_1
 /
A --- B --- C --- D --- F --- G
|            \
|             `-- H --- I --- J
|                        \
|                         `-- K
|\
| `-- b' -- c' -- h --- i --- j  branch_2*
 \
  `-- b'' - c'' - h' -- i' -- k  branch_3*
```

Note that `b`, `b'`, and `b''` are essentially equivalent commits.  The same thing goes for `c`, `c'`, and `c''`, `h` and `h'`, and `i` and `i'`.

Is there a halfway convenient way to achieve something like this:

```
A --- b --- c --- d --- f --- g  branch_1*
             \
              `-- h --- i --- j  branch_2
                         \
                          `-- k  branch_3
```

...where the modification to the `B` commit gets propagated through *all* the lineages it belongs to?

(I'd prefer a solution that also propagates the changes through to all the descendant stashes.)

Comment: You can't, but the middle case where you lose the structure is nonsense. Rebase off the new b and you preserve the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... is there a halfway convenient way to achieve [a sensible result]

No.

There's one command, `git filter-branch`, that *can* do it, but it's not halfway convenient, nor even 1/4th convenient.  It's about 1000% *in*convenient. :-)

The new `git rebase --rebase-merges` *machinery* is pretty obviously adaptable to doing this sort of thing in a more convenient way,<sup>1</sup> but it's not currently designed to rebase multiple branch names.

The new experimental [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) is capable enough to do what you want, and probably less inconvenient than `git filter-branch`, but it's still swatting bugs with nuclear weapons—in this case, maybe a moderately large bug, not just a fly, but still serious overkill.

(I once wrote my own experimental thing to do this sort of rebase, but I never finished it.  It did what I needed it to, when I needed it.  It worked using the equivalent of repeated `git rebase --onto` operations and had a lot of corner cases.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The key is to be able to *label* particular commits, so that after rebase copies them, you can pair up the <old, new> hash-ID pairs, and otherwise jump around the graph structure from one chain to another as the rebase progresses.  The old `--preserve-merges` code could not do that; the new `--rebase-merges` code can.  Once you have these pieces in place, rebasing multiple branches "simultaneously" is just a matter of saving multiple branch names to force-adjust after the rebase completes.  You then have the rebase list the correct commits and jump-points.  The main bulk of the rebase operation consists of copying those commits.  Last, using the old-to-new mapping, rebase can adjust each branch name, then reconnect `HEAD` to the one you want.

The remaining user-interface level problem lies in selecting the correct set of branch names to multi-rebase.

Comment: Thanks.  I find it surprising that this commonsensical capability has not been implemented.  Maybe it's too difficult to get right.  BTW, a complete solution should also transfer tags, something I didn't dare to hope for in my original post.

Comment: Both filter-branch and filter-repo can adjust tags (though you lose any PGP signatures). Current rebase will copy `git notes` entries; filter-branch doesn't and I don't know about filter-repo.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, if you rebase `branch_1`, changing `B`, you will get:

```
  ,-- b --- c --- d --- f --- g  branch_1*
 /
A --- B --- C --- D --- F --- G
             \
              `-- H --- I --- J  branch_2
                         \
                          `-- K  branch_3
```

You can then rebase `branch_2` onto `c` with:

```
git rebase --onto c C
```

yielding:

```
  ,-- b --- c --- d --- f --- g  branch_1*
 /           \
|             `-- h --- i --- j  branch_2
|
A --- B --- C --- D --- F --- G
             \
              `-- H --- I --- J
                         \
                          `-- K  branch_3
```

and then rebase `branch_3` onto `i`:

```
git rebase --onto i I
```

yielding:

```
  ,-- b --- c --- d --- f --- g  branch_1*
 /           \
|             `-- h --- i --- j  branch_2
|                        \
|                         `-- j  branch_3
|
A --- B --- C --- D --- F --- G
             \
              `-- H --- I --- J
                         \
                          `-- K
```

which will at least mirror your original branch structure.

Comment: This solution works for the toy example I gave, but it is hell to apply in the general case.  It requires examining a potentially complex graph, and one-by-one identifying the appropriate rebase points.  I've tried doing this sort of thing.  It's insane.

Comment: I can see how it could become impractical for complex cases but it's the best solution I know of to the problem as posed.